# How to get accumulated total in Netsuite saved search?

Tags: netsuite

I have a scenario where i have to take sum of a columns values in a linear fashion. I am using:-
 SUM({custrecord_hm_bc_payroll_net_pay}) OVER(PARTITION BY {custrecord_advs_hold_unhold_status} ORDER BY {custrecord_hm_bc_payroll_emp_id} ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To use Oracle's analytic functions in a Netsuite Saved Search you need to trick the system by inserting a comment -

```
SUM/* comment */({custrecord_hm_bc_payroll_net_pay}) OVER(PARTITION BY {custrecord_advs_hold_unhold_status} ORDER BY {custrecord_hm_bc_payroll_emp_id} ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

[Link](http://blog.prolecto.com/2015/05/26/solving-the-netsuite-cumulative-saved-search-tally-challenge/)

Comment: -- To Calculate Cumulative SUM or Running Totals:
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT BusinessEntityID AS SalesPersonID, CAST([Rate] AS DECIMAL(10,0))AS Salary, [ModifiedDate] AS SalDate
    FROM [HumanResources].[EmployeePayHistory]
    WHERE BusinessEntityID <= 10
    )
SELECT SalesPersonID, SalDate, Salary
   ,SUM(Salary) OVER (ORDER BY SalesPersonID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeSumByRows
   ,SUM(Salary) OVER (ORDER BY SalesPersonID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeSumByRange
FROM CTE
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, SalDate    "Can U specify the above expression in my context"

Comment: I am currently using :-  SUM/* comment */({custrecord_hm_bc_payroll_net_pay})OVER(PARTITION BY {custrecord_hm_bc_payroll_batch}ORDER BY {custrecord_hm_bc_payroll_emp_id}ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)   but it is not happening